# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

In Python, I'm trying to create code that iterates and checks if Gender is "E", and if yes, then if "IncState" is "ca", "california" (regardless of capitalization) or `None`, then it inserts "California", else it inserts the value in DefendantsTbl['IncState'][i].

I keep getting a "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." error.

This is sample data.

|  | Name | Gender | ShortName | Business | State | ZipCode | IncState | MergeName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Company1 | E | CWI | None | None | None | None | CWI |
| 1 | Company2 | E | None | None | None | None | Delaware | Company2 |

This is the code I am using.

```py
import os, sys
import pandas as pd 
from janitor import xlsx_table
from docx.shared import Inches, Pt
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
from time import perf_counter    
doc = Document()
docap = doc.add_paragraph

for i in range(len(DefendantsTbl)):
if DefendantsTbl['Gender'][i].lower() == 'e':
    docap('At all times material hereto, ' + DefendantsTbl['Name'][i] + ' was a ' 
+ ('California' if (str(DefendantsTbl['IncState'][i]).lower() == 'california') 
or (str(DefendantsTbl['IncState'][i]).lower() ==
'ca') or (DefendantsTbl['IncState'][i] is None)
else DefendantsTbl['IncState'][i]) + 'corporation that regularly transacted business in ' + CaseInfoTbl['County'] + ' County, California.')
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown when you want to get the `bool` of a `pandas.Series`:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series([1])
>>> bool(x)
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What you hit was a place where the operator implicitly converted the operands to bool (you used if but it also happens for and, or and while):

```py
>>> df or df
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> df and df
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> if df:
...     print('fun')
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> while df:
...     print('fun')
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```